American 'n' sound is sometimes retroflex?
In American English fast speech, I observed that the 'n' sound in certain words containing -rn- consonant clusters such as 'learning' and 'burning' appear to be pronounced as a voiced retroflex nasal [ɳ]
rather than a voiced alveolar nasal [n], thus yielding [ˈlɝɳɪŋ] instead of [ˈlɝnɪŋ] in the case of 'learning'. I would like to know if this is a recognized phenomenon.

@Lambie why would English have trill r-sound [r]?

Presumably you need to consult "the open Carnegie Mellon University Pronouncing Dictionary" for the meaning of [r] used here.

Apologies for the misinterpretation. However, I think the phonetic transcription is too broad and unreliable.

@AehkGuu Unfortunately, despite that website's name, it's actually producing phonemic transcriptions, not phonetic ones.

(As shown by the fact that, in "American English" mode, it transcribes hand as [hænd] instead of showing æ-tensing as a proper phonetic transcription would.)

@Lambie As that website's FAQ notes, it's actually providing phonemic transcriptions, not phonetic ones. Why the website is named "To Phonetics" I do not know.

Yes, this is a recognized phenomenon. There was a related question I answered a while back about how, in American English, a flapped /d/ after /r/ can become a retroflex flap [ɽ]. Since /n/ can also undergo flapping, the same phenomenon occurs, making a nasal retroflex flap [ɽ̃].
